# Is there any way to display null values (as string) in a multi-value parameter using FetchXml query in SSRS reports?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I'm learning **SSRS** and stuck in a scenario where I want to display some records (containing null values) in a **multi-value parameter**. I'm using **Dynamics 365 Fetch** query. For a simple drop-down allow null works but for multi-values it's not working. Is there any way how can I make it work?
**Remember**, I'm able to retrieve the null values but what I want is to display those null values as string, like 'Null', in the multi-value parameter list

**This is my main query:**

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="contact">
<attribute name="fullname"/>
<attribute name="telephone1"/>
<attribute name="jobtitle"/>
<attribute name="emailaddress1"/>
<attribute name="creditlimit"/>
<attribute name="parentcustomerid"/>
<attribute name="birthdate"/>
<attribute name="address1_stateorprovince"/>
<attribute name="address1_country"/>
<attribute name="address1_city"/>
<order attribute="fullname" descending="false"/>
<filter>
<condition attribute="telephone1" operator="not-null"/>
</filter>
<filter>
<condition attribute="emailaddress1" operator="not-null"/>
</filter>
<filter type="or">
<condition attribute="jobtitle" operator="null">
<value>Null</value>
</condition>
<condition attribute="jobtitle" operator="in" value="@jobtitle"/>
</filter>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

**Parameter gets values through this:**

```
<fetch distinct="true">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="jobtitle" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="telephone1" operator="not-null" />
    </filter>
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="emailaddress1" operator="not-null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

*Although null values exists there but I want them to show as string 'Null'...*

Comment: If you convert the null value to a string in both the parameter and the dataset you're filtering, it'll work. I've used `<Blank>`.

Comment: Hi @aduguid, Can u please show me some code on how to do this as I tried a lot on this but am not able to solve this.